# Label won't add to input in JS

Tags: javascript, html, label

I have this test function:

```js
function testFunction2(){
    const testinput = document.createElement("input",{type:"text",id:"test"})
    const testlabel = document.createElement("label",{htmlfor:"test",textcontent:"Test"})

    document.body.appendChild(testlabel);
    document.body.appendChild(testinput);
}
```

```html
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="testFunction2();">Click Me</button>
</body>
```

That should add a text box and a label when I click a button. Instead only the text box is added.

I have tried using a few different attributes of the label element, as well as assigning the attributes after creating the element (for the label, it seems to work fine for the input).

Comment: That’s not what the second argument of [`createElement`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) is used for. Did you mean `const testInput = Object.assign(document.createElement("input"), { type: "text", id: "test" }), testLabel = Object.assign(document.createElement("label"), { htmlFor: "test", textContent: "Test" }); document.body.append(testLabel, testInput);`?

Comment: Apparently I did! I just pasted in your code and it seems to work more or less as expected. Thank you very much. I am just learning, so my attempt was a bit of a Frankenstein's monster.

Comment: See [`Object.assign`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). When in doubt, read the documentation. Also, Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** tab. Inspect your elements. You said _“Instead only the text box is added”_, but that’s wrong. Both elements are added; your label is just empty. If you used the Inspector, you would’ve seen that the element got added.

Comment: If possible, could you explain what the second argument of createElement is for? And the purpose of "object.assign"? Edit: I will be returning to the documentation with a fervor, thanks again! Edit 2: Inspector! Duh! That is seriously cool, I was stuck in the mud.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement#parameters) the `options` object only allows one property, and that is related to web components.

You'll need to assign the various values manually.

```js
const testinput = document.createElement('input');
testinput.type = 'text';
testinput.id = 'test';

const testlabel = document.createElement('label');
testlabel.setAttribute('for', 'test');
testlabel.textContent = 'Test';

document.body.appendChild(testlabel)
document.body.appendChild(testinput)
```

Comment: This solution works as well! You've given me a lot to read in the documentation, because I only partly understand what the difference is (for now). Thank you!